# How Do I Access A Snippet Option In Lift?

Tags: scala, lift

If I have a template like this:

```
<div class="lift:ThisIsMySnippet?option1=a_value;option2=another_value">
  <div class="morestuff">
    {embed}
  </div>
</div>
```

and then a snippet like this:

```
class ThisIsMySnippet {

  // I want option1's value!

}
```

How do I get those values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can get the param values of a snippet via the `S` object like this:

```
val x = S.attr("option1")
```

In this case, `x` will be a `Box[String]`, so if you want to get the value in a safe way you could do this:

```
val x = S.attr("option1") openOr "defaultValue"
```